# Combined textures TGA export color problem

Tags: export, image

Today I wanted to automate the combined texture creation (for unreal) using the Blender compositor so that I wouldn't have to do it by hand in photoshop.

The node settings are quite simple, four different textures combined with the RGBA channels of an other texture to export.

Specular/Metalness (with a switch) => R channel
Roughness => G channel
Displace => B channel
Ambiant Occlusion => A channel

But ...

If I export this final texture to TGA, the alpha channel change the differents colors channels.

If I export in open EXR, it's fine.

Do you have any idea where the problem could come from?

Thank you

In this capture only blue channel is selected for the both textures

[image: TGA vs EXR : only blue chanel]